# (DOORS/DXL) Possible to use DXL to open new windows of modules?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

Is it possible to use DXL to programmatically open up a module in a new window?
Also, would it be possible to programmatically scroll to a defined object in a module?

If so for either of these, can you please point me to functions or methods I should use?

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do both of those

```
Module m = read("/PROJECT/MODULE NAME", true)
Object o = object(THE_OBJECT_ID, m)
current = o
refresh m
```

THE_OBJECT_ID is just the number of the object you want the focus to be on.

Let me know if you run into any problems.